# Multidimensional version of "kron" product?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

Now I have a matrix A of dimension N by p, and the other matrix B of dimension N by q. What I want to have is a matrix, say C, of dimension N by pq such that

```
C(i,:) = kron(A(i,:), B(i,:));
```

If N is large, loop over N rows may take quite long time. So currently I am augmenting A and B appropriately(combining usage of *repmat*, *permute* and *reshape*) to turn each matrix of dimension N by pq, and then formulating C by something like

```
C = A_aug .* B_aug;
```

Any better idea?

Comment: Check out `superkron` on MATLAB's FileExchange - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32578-superkron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout some [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) + [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) + [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) magic -

```
out = reshape(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 3 2]),B),size(A,1),[])
```

---

**Benchmarking & Verification**

Benchmarking code -

```
%// Setup inputs
N = 200;
p = 190;
q = 180;
A = rand(N,p);
B = rand(N,q);

disp('--------------------------------------- Without magic')
tic
C = zeros(size(A,1),size(A,2)*size(B,2));
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    C(i,:) = kron(A(i,:), B(i,:));
end
toc

disp('--------------------------------------- With some magic')
tic
out = reshape(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 3 2]),B),size(A,1),[]);
toc

error_val = max(abs(C(:)-out(:)))
```

Output -

```
--------------------------------------- Without magic
Elapsed time is 0.524396 seconds.
--------------------------------------- With some magic
Elapsed time is 0.055082 seconds.
error_val =
     0
```